# Function in Java that intelligently rounds up or down?

Tags: java, rounding

I am looking for a Java function that rounds up or down, but normally, like 3.2 to 3, and 3.6 to 4. There are a bunch of answers, but all of them either rounding up exclusively or rounding down exclusively. If there is not one then I guess I will have to create it, but just wanted to see if anyone else has ever wanted the same and found one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not totally convinced you looked very hard ;)

Comment: Haha, I did! The answer provided doesn't make sense, so I brushed it off. My fault though.

Comment: I'm not sure what "intelligence" has to do with this.  Rounding versus truncation is a seriously dumb algorithm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29):

> **public static int round(float a)**
>
> Returns the closest int to the argument. The result is rounded to an integer by adding 1/2, taking the floor of the result, and casting
> the result to type int. In other words, the result is equal to the
> value of the expression:
>
> (int)Math.floor(a + 0.5f)
>
> Parameters:
>
> - a - a floating-point value to be rounded to an integer.
>
> Returns:
>
> the value of the argument rounded to the nearest int value.

Comment: I actually looked at that, but the way its written is confusing.. guess thats my blonde moment